# How to correctly apply volume gain digitally?

Tags: java, android, volume

I have an audio app to record very low wildlife sounds, and I thus need to raise the playback volume digitally with a (float) `gain` factor. The files are 16 bit WAVE mono, 44100.

What I do now is the following:

```
AudioTrack mplayer = new AudioTrack(....);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(songfile);
...
while (isPlaying() && (i = is.read(music)) != -1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i / 2; j++) {
        shortv = ((music[j * 2] & 0xff) | (music[j * 2 + 1] << 8));
        musics[j] = (short) Math.max(Math.min(gain * shortv, Short.MAX_VALUE), Short.MIN_VALUE);
    }

    if (isPlaying()) mplayer.write(musics, 0, j);
}
...
```

As you can see, I just multiply the `short` extracted from the two bytes, with the `gain`, which goes from 0 to 100 (the max/min is to limit in the `short` range).

My problem is that when `gain` is too high, I hear distortions. This is expected, of course. Yet, when `gain` is high the above code gives "pixelation" (sorry, a photographer here!). Namely, the values of `musics[]` is 0, 100, 200, 300... I wonder how much of the distortion comes from the tiny speakers and how much from the "pixelation"...

Is there a natural/well-known/frequently-used/standard method to deal with this "pixelation"? Of course I could just "blur" (sorry...) the signal with a filter, but I wonder is there is something more effective.

Or maybe I am being too picky since the signal is already in 16 bits?

Comment: How did your program compile with a variable named `short`?

Comment: I think your distortions are mainly [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(audio))

Comment: `short` was just a name to write the code here, sorry. I will fix that. Regarding the clipping, it could be, but the waveform does not show that.